# How can I make protected or private routes in next 13

Tags: next.js, frameworks, next-auth

I'm new to next 13. I created the pages in app. Like about, contact, dashboard.
In dashboard I have (auth). If the user has a token he can visit the dashboard otherwise he will be redirected to the login page.

How can I do this in next 13. It was quite easy in React js

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are some alternatives you can follow for example, once the use makes the API call to sign you receive back the token you store it in local storage then inside `useEffect` of each page you want the user to be signed in to see it, you check if the token does not exist so you redirect it to the login page.

the most protected way to handle user authentification in nextjs is with the [Next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example) library
 the idea is to create a session for each user logged in using Next-auth. in your case you are using a nodejs backend you want to login with next-auth using the [credentials provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials#options). this provider allows you to create your session based on values passed to the [signIn](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin) method so you can use these values (email, password) to make an API call to your backend and receive back the user information + the access token and store them in the session.
 there are several [options](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options) you can put in your `authOptions` object that you export from `[...nextauth].js` file.

you can find [here](https://codevoweb.com/setup-and-use-nextauth-in-nextjs-13-app-directory/) a very interesting tutorial explaining in detail how to setup and use NextAuth in Next.js 13 App Directory

Comment: I have gone through the next auth tutorial, and I find it interesting. However, I am wondering how I can pass the data that is coming from the backend to the auth session. I would like to avoid client-side next-auth authentication.

Comment: of course, next-auth works server side, with the credentials provider, you fetch data inside the `authorize` function then you return the user from this function, then with the help of JWT callback and session callback you update your token and session

Answer (score 1):

You can use next-auth, as you may already know because you tagged your question with next-auth.
Setup next-auth as desribed in the [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/introduction). For serverpages you can use [getServerSession](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#unstable_getserversession).

Your app/dashboard/page.jsx could look like this:

```js
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function Show({ params }) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    if (!session) {
        redirect("path/to/loginpage");
    }
    return (
        <main>
            {/* replace this by the content you want to display */}
            You're logged in as {session.user.name}.
        </main>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have a backend in node js. I will send the data to them they will response with a token. On the base of token i want authorization.

Comment: Like if i have a token i can visit dashboard otherwise i'll redirect to login page

Comment: Can you share a code-sample that shows how you're getting the token? You probably can adapt my code and just use your token in the if query.

Comment: I didn't write the code yet. That is the problem. Can you please help me with implementing the logic. I will get it with one basic example

Comment: I have no experience implementing authentication myself as I've used next-auth for something like this before. No matter what you decide to do, the best thing to do is just start writing code and trying it out. If you get stuck then at least you have some code to post here that can serve as a starting point.